# MS Access - Will It Work Here?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

The situation is this: I need to create a basic work management database for a government agency. While I would prefer to code up a more robust platform, government statute/procurement baloney would likely prevent us from writing and deploying our own coded solution, so we're stuck with essentially one option - building something MS Access.

I've done quite a bit of research on the subject, and it sounds like it would theoretically be possible to make this work based on our scenario, but I need some additional input from people who have deployed large-scale Access applications before. Essentially, I need to know if this project has a chance of working or if I should put it out of its misery before I get started.

The scenario is as follows:

- About 40 users
- All users are in the same physical location (and I believe on the same physical network setup as well)
- The system would need to be able to handle a lot of simultaneous reading and writing
- The database would be relatively simple, probably less than 10-15 tables and a similar number of forms. (Unsure on the number of queries as of yet.)
- I would of course do my best to follow best practices (splitting the DB, limiting query results, etc.)

What do you think? Would Access be able to handle that kind of load and maintain decent performance over a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work, but it would be my last resort. A mySQL & php solution is free, but if you have to go this route...

You want to make sure to split the project with the front end loaded on each user's PC and the back end on good server. The front end has all the queries, forms, and reports. The back end has the data tables and each of the tables is linked to the front ends.

I have been running a 4 user database over the network for 7 years without any corruption glitches, but we don't have a lot of simultaneous writes. Backup often. It is reasonably fast once Access is running and the database loaded.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks. PHP and MySQL is what I'd like to use, but again, there are those pesky laws and regulations (our centralized technology dept has what amounts to a monopoly on all of our coding and hosting, even on things that we could do ourselves).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would. I work for a company that does this for about 85 users. There are at least 40+ tables that have been put together over the years. The guy who set these up has about 8 copies that a user can open at any time so nobody has to get locked out.